# Dict Same Key - Example 39 Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python, dictionary

new to coding and working through Zed Shaw's Learn Python3 the Hard way.

I wanted to make a dict that maps a key to multiple cities but quickly found out that each key has to be unique and reusing the same key simply overwrites the previous value.

Here is my original code:

```
states = {
    'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
    'Maryland': 'MD',
    'Texas': 'TX'}

cities = {
    'PA': 'State College',
    'PA': 'Spring Mills',
    'PA': 'Pittsburgh',
    'PA': 'Philadelphia',
    'PA': 'Eerie',
    'MD': 'Frederick',
    'MD': 'Salisbury',
    'MD': 'Swanton',
    'MD': 'Baltimore',
    'TX': 'Midland',
    'TX': 'Dallas',
    'TX': 'Houston',
    'TX': 'Galveston'
}

for state, abbrev in states.items():
    x = "%s is abbreviated: %s" % (state, abbrev)
    print(x)

for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    x = "%s has the city %s in it" % (abbrev, city)
    print(x)
```

The next thing I found was that you could use a list as a value in the dict.  So I tried that instead and made a nested for loop to call each city individually:

```
states = {
    'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
    'Maryland': 'MD',
    'Texas': 'TX'}

cities = {
    'PA': ['State College',
    'Spring Mills',
    'Pittsburgh',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Eerie'],
    'MD': ['Frederick',
    'Salisbury',
    'Swanton',
    'Baltimore'],
    'TX': ['Midland',
    'Dallas',
    'Houston',
    'Galveston']
}

for state, abbrev in states.items():
    x = "%s is abbreviated: %s" % (state, abbrev)
    print(x)

for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    count = 0
    for i in cities.get(abbrev):
        city_list = cities.get(abbrev)
        x = "%s has the city %s in it" % (abbrev, city_list[count])
        print(x)
        count += 1
```

My question is if there is a better (more simplified?) method to map multiple cities to a single state and grab that value later on or if a list inside a dict is the best method here. It is possible I haven't gotten to a better method in the book yet but am open to all responses.  Thanks for taking the time to read the post. Hope it was not too long winded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you did -- that's probably the way I would do it if I had to solve this problem. The only improvement you might be able to make, which will likely be mentioned later in the book, would be making a class for each state and then storing the abbreviation in an attribute like so:

```
class State:
def __init__(self, name, abbreviation, cities):
    self.name = name
    self.abbreviation = abbreviation
    self.cities = cities
    
penn = State("Pennsylvania", "PA", ["Pittsburgh", "Philadelphia", "Hershey"])
print(penn.name)
print(penn.abbreviation)
print(penn.cities)
```

You will find that as you move to more and more complicated programs, class structures become more and more useful. I find myself using something like a class even in more functional programming languages.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond J.D. Looks like classes will definitely be useful moving forward and could help keep my code more organized and easier to read.  I looked forward in the book and classes are in the next few examples. I will use your code and what I learn in the next few exercises to come back to this exercise and try it again.

Upvoted/accepted your answer but don't have enough reputation for the upvote to show yet since that was my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of dictionary and lists is not bad. I see such things when I'm working with APIs. I could simplify your second 'for loop' to:

```
for abbrev, cities in cities.items():
    for city in cities:
        print("%s has the city %s in it" % (abbrev, city))
```

What is also important here, regarding to the modified code - the problems may occur if you, or someone else will add to dictionary next pair (key=value) where value will not be a list. New pair should contains value as a list, even with single element.

Take a look to defaultdict, to provide some actions to block possible issues if you want to continue your container in this way.

Like already J.D. Rudie mentioned, a class is also great solution fo readability and performance. To understand why, search some information regarding to key-sharing dictionary.

Comment: ahhhh, that does simplify my solution a bit.  I like how the second for loop called the variable/list "cities" that is looped over in the first for loop.  Thank you. same as to JD's response, I upvoted but it doesn't show publicly yet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, thank you both for the answers.  The past two days I have been learning about Classes and basics of OOP. I took both of your advice and wrote the following new code:

```
class State(object):

    def __init__ (self, State, Abbrev, City):
        self.State = State
        self.Abbrev = Abbrev
        self.City = City

states = [
    'Pennsylvania',
    'Maryland',
    'Texas']

states.sort()

Abbrev_dict = {'Pennsylvania':'PA','Maryland': 'MD','Texas': 'TX'}

city_dict = {
    'PA': ['State College',
    'Spring Mills',
    'Pittsburgh',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Eerie'],
    'MD': ['Frederick',
    'Salisbury',
    'Swanton',
    'Baltimore'],
    'TX': ['Midland',
    'Dallas',
    'Houston',
    'Galveston']
}

state_list = []
for state in states:
    abbrev = Abbrev_dict[state]
    cities = city_dict[abbrev]
    state_list = State(state, abbrev, cities)
    print(state_list.State, state_list.Abbrev, state_list.City)
```

Both of your answers helped me understand classes and for loops better so thank you for that.  I am posting my updated code so that someone in the future may be able to reference it and see how I applied your suggestions to the example from the book.

edit: If I was going to do this for all 50 states I would first sort the list "states" in alphabetical order, otherwise by looking at the objects in state_list you wouldn't know which object corresponds to which state if you wanted to call the variable.

edit: ^^ added the sort to the code to list the states in alphabetical order